# Dynamic ChoiceFilter that excutes when page loads in django

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) and trying to make a custom, dynamic, CHOICES list that also has an option to pass a "blank" string (to Show All). The following code in my filters.py is working OK, however the code is executed when the web-server starts, not each time the page is loaded. So if anyone adds a Plant, this is not reflected in the filters drop-down choices unless the web-server is restarted. How can I go about having this evaluate when the page loads?

Code from my filters.py

```
def createplantchoices():
    PLANT_CHOICES= [['', 'Show All'],]
    plant_list = Plant.objects.all().order_by('manufacturer')
    for plant in plant_list:
        PLANT_CHOICES.append([plant.id , plant.plant_number + " - " + plant.manufacturer],)

    return PLANT_CHOICES


class SightingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    plant_number = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=createplantchoices())
    state = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = Sighting
        fields = ['city', 'store', 'brand', 'product', 'flavor', 'fat', 'size']
```

**Edit 2/28/15**

If I put the code in the **init** like so:

```
class SightingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SightingFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['plant_number'] = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=createplantchoices())

    state = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = Sighting
        fields = ['city', 'store', 'brand', 'product', 'flavor', 'fat', 'size']
```

Then the drop down is evaluated when the page loads like I want. However, now when I try to apply the filter I am getting the error **Cannot resolve keyword u'None' into field. Choices are:** then it lists all the fields in my model. This error didn't happen with my original code.

Full Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://dev.mysite.org/?city=&store=&brand=&product=&flavor=&fat=&size=&state=&plant_number=3

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'axes',
 'imagekit',
 'yogurt')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware',
 'comp.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /srv/www/mysite/templates/dashboard.html, error at line 7
   Cannot resolve keyword u'None' into field. Choices are: plant_number, plant_number_id, brand, city, date, fat, flavor, id, photo, price, product, size, slug, state, store
   1 : {% extends "base.html" %}


   2 : {% load humanize %}


   3 : {% block content %}


   4 : <form action="" method="get">


   5 :  <div id="fil" style="clear:both;">


   6 :      <p><b>Filters</b></p>


   7 :          {{ filter.form.as_ul }} 


   8 :     </div>  


   9 :     <div style="clear:both; margin-left:30px";>


   10 :         <input type="submit" value="Filter Results"/>


   11 :         <input type="submit" name="Clear Filters" value="Clear Filters" />


   12 :   </div>


   13 :      </form>


   14 :      <div id="indent">


   15 :     {% for obj in filter %}


   16 :         <a href="/sighting/{{ obj.slug }}/ ">{{ obj.date|date:"m/d/Y" }} {{ obj.brand }} ${{ obj.price|intcomma }} </a><br />


   17 :     {% endfor %}


Traceback:
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "./yogurt/views.py" in dashboard
  20.         return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  23.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  178.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  90.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  596.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  734.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  764.                     current = current[bit]
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py" in __getitem__
  293.         return self.qs[key]
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py" in qs
  324.                     qs = filter_.filter(qs, value)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_filters/filters.py" in filter
  78.         qs = method(**{'%s__%s' % (self.name, lookup): value})
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  691.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  709.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1287.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1314.                     current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1138.         lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1076.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
  1383.             self.raise_field_error(opts, name)
File "/opt/comp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in raise_field_error
  1389.                          "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword u'None' into field. Choices are: plant_number, plant_number_id, brand, city, date, fat, flavor, id, photo, price, product, size, slug, state, store
```

**EDIT 1/29/15**
dashboard code in views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    if "Clear Filters" in request.GET:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        filter = SightingFilter(request.GET, queryset=Sighting.objects.all())
        context = {'filter': filter, 'request': request}
        return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: you need to do this in the form rather than the model

Comment: This isn't in models.py it is filter.py. [Django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) doesn't user forms.py

Comment: ok fair enough, but the same principal applies... `SightingFilter` is analogous to a `ModelForm` with a `ChoiceField`... you need to move your choices logic into the `__init__` method of the filter class instead of code executed at import time

Comment: Anentropic, please see my edit above. Putting the code in the __init__ causes it to update on page loads like I want but is now causing other problems.

Comment: well maybe post the stacktrace, or even have a look through it to work out where it is going wrong

Comment: I assume stacktrace and what I see on the debug page are the same. If not then I am not sure how to get the stacktrace. I have included the full error message. For some reason it doesn't like {{ filter.form.as_ul }} in the template.

Comment: it looks like possibly because you don't have a `plant_number` filter defined on the filterset any more... I think you probably still need to specify something like `plant_number = django_filters.ChoiceFilter()` as well as what you do in `__init__`

Comment: I don't think so, I tried adding plant_number but that didn't help same error. I am pretty sure the __init__ line "self.filters['plant_number']  = ..." is not creating the same thing as plant_number = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=createplantchoices()). I tried putting just self.plant_number = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=createplantchoices()) under __init__ and that made "plant_number" disappear from my filters all together.

Comment: yes that's the problem I meant, you need to add the `plant_number = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=createplantchoices())` back into your `SightingFilter` definition like you originally had (ie outside the `__init__` method) _as well as_ what you now have in `__init__`

Comment: Yea I tried that already. When I do that it gives me the same error about: Cannot resolve keyword u'None' into field.

Comment: could you post the `dashboard` view code too

Comment: Anentropic, I have posted my dashboard view code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Anetropic, can you remove the "possible duplicate". Since I am clearing having a different issue.